# Cannot solved an issue

Tags: reactjs

I have this :

```
window.setInterval({} => {
  n++
render()
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: change `{} => {n++}` for `() => {n++}`

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` callback function is incorrect and/or incomplete (appears incomplete because of code block provided).

```js
// {}, needs to be ()
window.setInterval(() => {
  n++
  // move `render()` here if it needs to run each interval
}, 100) // need to close arrow function and pass interval time.

render()
```